# Turn dataset to matrix and keep the "sample" column to run prcomp in R

Tags: r, matrix, prcomp

I have a dataset that looks like this:

| sample | area | trnsp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2,455 | 134,23 |
| b | 2,009 | 176,32 |
| c | 1,997 | 200,01 |
| d | 2,309 | 149,87 |

If I run `prcomp(data)`  I will get a must be numeric error because the sample column is a character. I was thinking turn in it into a matrix but then the sample column is turned into a factor and assigned a number.
I was wondering if it is possible to convert the data into a matrix with this form:

|  | area | trnsp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2,455 | 134,23 |
| b | 2,009 | 176,32 |
| c | 1,997 | 200,01 |
| d | 2,309 | 149,87 |

I am very sorry if this has been asked before I search and only find the ones that turn datasets into matrix assigning a numeric value to the character column

Thank you for all your help

Answer (score 1):

Turn sample names into rownames and remove the column name.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. The columns area and trnsp are recognized as numeric but the sample column is chr, that is why prcomp doesn't run. that is why I would like to make a matrix to maybe solve the problem and keep the sample names to use when I plot it

Comment: In that case, make sample names rownames and remove the column.